Azure App Service Authentication: 403 Forbidden Error When Calling API Between Two Apps
Environment
Platform: Azure App Service
Number of Applications: 2
Authentication: App Service Authentication enabled on both apps
Framework: FastAPI

Problem Description
I have two FastAPI applications deployed on Azure App Service with App Service Authentication enabled. When attempting to call an API from one app to another, I consistently receive a 403 Forbidden error.
Authentication:

App_service_A:

App_service_B:

Code Snippet (Calling the API of App Service A from App Service B)
 # Example API call code
 from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
 credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
 import requests
 token = credential.get_token("api://{client_id_app_service_A}/max**")
 api_url = "https://*.azurewebsites.net/api/task"
 headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token.token}'
    }


 response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
 print("============================Response==============================", response)
 print(response.json)

